# Using the HTML5 boiler plate I would like to know how I could place all my scripts in the plug-ins.js and scripts.js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a demo files of the script I wish to place in these files in order to use the build script that comes with the HTML5 boiler plate. http://epecho.com/tst/index.html

Answer (score 0):

those files have been "minified";

```
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<!--<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>-->
```

However, if you want to modify them, you can just ad your own javascript to the file.  Just make sure you do not overwrite them every time you update the scripts.

```
// your code goes here..
function foo() { 
}

window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];
  log.history.push(arguments);
  arguments.callee = arguments.callee.caller;  
  if(this.console) console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
};
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();)b[a]=b[a]||c})(window.console=window.console||{});
```

It is probably not good practice to do this, would be best to just make a new javascript file, and place your code in that file, and include it.

Create a file called whatever you like, "my code.js" is used in my example, and then include that as below in the html page.

```
<script src="js/mycode.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the plug-ins.js file I would wrap all my scripts in a on document load, right?

Comment: Ok, I have been at this a while I am making slow progress but I think I have it. I have plastid the scripts that I have written for my site in the HTML5 Boiler Plate script.js file. I have placed any Jquery plug-ins like slide deck into the HTML5 Boiler plate plug-ins.js file. The problem that I have is that in boiler plate they are placed at the end of the HTML doc but when placed there they do not work. I have placed them in the head of my html doc and they work just fine. I would like to keep my docs in line with best practices. How would I place them at the bottom so that slide deck works?